# How to set DOM Element Property (ScrollLeft) in Vue 3 Using Composition

Tags: vue.js, dom, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I'm trying to get a DOM element that is horizontally scrollable and set it's scroll position. However the property doesn't seem to update it's value even if I output it's value in a `console.log()` immediately after the assignment.

```js
<script setup>
import {ref, watch} from 'vue';

const container = ref();

watch(container, () => {
  console.log(container.value.scrollWidth); // Output: 1500
  console.log(container.value.scrollLeft); // Output: 0
  container.value.scrollLeft = 33;
  console.log(container.value.scrollLeft); // ❌ Output: 0, Expected: 33
})
</script>

<template>
  <div ref="container"></div>
</template>
```

FYI, I'm using `watch()` instead of `onMounted()` because I don't know what the scroll position should be until after I make a `fetch()` call in the parent component. The full version of the `<script>` section is given below, however the above version can be thrown in a vue playground and will run showing the issue.

I've googled this nine ways to Sunday. I can find articles about Vue 2, Vue 3 Options API, or Vue 3 Composition. I am new to Vue and have only ever used Vue 3 Composition API. Either way, all the articles or stack overflow questions seem to be about accessing (reading) DOM elements using template refs, but they don't show how to assign a value to a DOM element property. The above code get's me as far as reading the properties, but when I try to assign a new value to a property that property doesn't get updated.

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref, watch } from "vue";
import type { ProbeRequest } from "@/types/classes/ProbeRequest";
import type { ProbeRequestStatus } from "@/types/classes/ProbeRequestStatus";
import { buildTracker, getScrollPosition } from "./utils";

interface Props {
  probeRequest: null | ProbeRequest;
}

const props = withDefaults(defineProps<Props>(), { probeRequest: null });
const tracker = ref<(ProbeRequestStatus | string)[]>([]);
const trackerContainer = ref();

watch(
  () => props.probeRequest,
  (probeRequest) => {
    tracker.value = probeRequest ? buildTracker(probeRequest) : [];
    if (tracker.value.length > 0) {
      console.log(trackerContainer.value.scrollWidth);
      console.log(trackerContainer.value.scrollLeft);
      const scrollLeft = getScrollPosition(
        tracker.value,
        trackerContainer.value.scrollWidth
      );
      trackerContainer.value.scrollLeft = scrollLeft;
      console.log(trackerContainer.value.scrollLeft);
    }
  }
);
</script>
```

Comment: The documentation for watch may give you a clue, i'm surprised that's not one of the things you mentioned googling for

Comment: I did read the documentation. Sorry I didn't call that out explicitly. If there is a clue in there I'm not seeing it. As far as I can tell I'm doing everything I'm supposed to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the problem was that on the first render, the container was not being overflowed because there was no content (I'm waiting on `tracker.value` to be an array with multiple elements; and that is waiting on `props.probeRequest` to have a value). That means that `scrollLeft` had to be `0`. (It's worth noting that is also why my contrived example didn't work because it was never scrollable)

Once the container had content I then needed to wait for it to be rendered before I could assign a value to `scrollLeft`. So I had to add an `await nextTick()` (didn't know that was a thing).

Code now looks like this:

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref, watch, nextTick } from "vue";
import type { ProbeRequest } from "@/types/classes/ProbeRequest";
import type { ProbeRequestStatus } from "@/types/classes/ProbeRequestStatus";
import { buildTracker, getScrollPosition } from "./utils";

interface Props {
  probeRequest: null | ProbeRequest;
}

const props = withDefaults(defineProps<Props>(), { probeRequest: null });
const tracker = ref<(ProbeRequestStatus | string)[]>([]);
const trackerContainer = ref<HTMLInputElement | null>(null);

watch(
  () => props.probeRequest,
  async (probeRequest) => {
    tracker.value = probeRequest ? buildTracker(probeRequest) : [];

    await nextTick() // ✅ Here is the magic sauce

    if (trackerContainer.value && tracker.value.length > 0) {
      console.log(trackerContainer.value.scrollWidth);
      console.log(trackerContainer.value.scrollLeft);
      const scrollLeft = getScrollPosition(
        tracker.value,
        trackerContainer.value.scrollWidth
      );
      trackerContainer.value.scrollLeft = scrollLeft;
      console.log(trackerContainer.value.scrollLeft);
    }
  }
);
</script>
```

Thanks @tachibana-shin for the inspiration!

Comment: Glad you figured it out.  By the way there's a way to shorten your if statement, you can now write `if (trackerContainer.value?.length > 0)`

Comment: the first condition is checking the value of `trackerContainer` while the second condition is checking the value of `tracker`. But otherwise a noteworthy comment if the were both `trackerContainer`

Comment: You seriously didn't think I knew what your code was doing?  I've receommended to you some new Javascript  syntax and it is *absolutely on point*, your comment notwithstanding.  Did you even try it?  I'm trying to help you, and you insult me

Comment: Sorry, I thought you misread and saw this`(trackeContainer.value && trackerContainer.value.length` instead of what I put. Now I understand you're saying the second check isn't needed because if `tracker.value.length > 0`, then it would follow that `trackerContainer.value` would have children elements and I could check that. However, your code is still wrong because it's not `trackerContainer.value?.length` but rather `trackerContainer.value?.children?.length`. Good idea, thanks!

Comment: That said, the idea still doesn't quite work because `trackerContainer.value?.children?.length > 0` gives a typescript error `trackerContainer.value.children.length is possibly 'undefined'`

Comment: You are being astoundingly disingenuous.  My code is correct based on the code you posted. You made *absolutely no mention of children* until your latest comments.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a dom problem i bet your `ref='container'` is not scrollable:
More: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollLeft

Comment: Not a bad callout. In my example above that works in the playground that might actually be the issue

However, in the full code I have the container overflow-x set to auto, and it has a scrollWidth of 1500. I open the page in a browser with a width of 720px, and the element shows a scroll bar that works when viewed

Comment: I just tried setting overflow-x to scroll, gave it a width of 500px knowing the content is larger, and ran it. still same issue.

Comment: I tried updated the code snippet above giving it a width, overflow-x scroll, and gave it overflow content, and it worked. I'm betting that my container is the old container before i give it overflowing content. It's too late for me to test now, but first thing in the morning I'll give it a shot. Thanks for the input, I think it might have lead me where i need to go :D